# Add Directive template in option of select tag

Tags: html, angularjs

i have directive which return template --

```
angular.module('ui-module').directive(
    'onelineDir',
    ['$http', '$compile','$timeout',
            function($http, $compile,$timeout) {
            function controller($scope, $attrs) {
            }

            return {
                    restrict : 'E',
                    transclude : false,
                    scope : {
                        dir : '=',
                        img : '='
                    },
                    controller : controller,
                    link : function($scope, element, attrs) {

                        $scope.showModal = function() {


                        };
                    },
                    template : '<span><span ng-click="showModal()">Add New</span></span>',
                    replace : true
                };

                }]);
```

and in html select tag is below--

```
       <select class="input-xlarge" ui-select2  name="category" ng-model="file.category" ng-disabled="file.fileError==='true' && file.duplicate==='false'">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option ng-repeat="c in categories" value ={{c.id}}>{{c.description}}</option>
            <option value="n"><oneline-dir dir="dirItem" img="true" ng-disabled="file.fileError==='true'"></oneline-dir></option>
        </select>
```

above i am trying to put directive template like Add New as option.
but it is not replacing template.

if i use directive outside select tag it working fine and it is display as Add New.

please give me some suggestion to solve this.

Comment: Post the directive code.

Comment: I guess you can use `ngTransclude` to achieve what you required.